# Substring continue to search until specific character

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, substring

I am getting a string at the run time. The string is in JSON format( key value pair). One of the key is "`userId`". I need to retrieve the value of `userId`. The problem is I don't know the position of "`userId`" key. The string can look like `{"name":"XX", "userId":"YYY","age":"10"}` or it can look like `{"age":"10", "name":"XX", "userId":"YYY"}` or it can look like this `{"age":"10"}`

I am thinking of using `substring()`

```
var index = myString.IndexOf("userId\":\"");
if(index != -1){
  myString.Subtring(index, ???)//How to specify the length here
}
```

I am not sure, how to say continue until you find next `"` (double quote)

Comment: Why don't you just deserialize the JSON instead of re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: Use a proper JSON parser and actually read the data. Don't try and parse it yourself with string functions.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: I though of desterilizing the JSON, but the format of string is not fixed.

Comment: I agree with the other comments that it is ridiculous to try to write a dumbed-down JSON parser yourself. Just do it right and use the existing tools. That said, the little bit of code you posted shows you're aware of the `string.IndexOf()` method to find the text `"userId:"`. So if you're aware of that, why aren't you aware of using the [same method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the text `"\""`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Thanks. I see what you are saying.

Comment: `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(myString, "\"userId\":\"([^\"]+)").Groups[1].Value`

Comment: @OpenStack what in the world does `the format of string is not fixed.` mean?

Comment: @ErikPhilips: By that I mean the number of keys and their order may differ in the json string. After reading your comment, I now understand that I was not clear enough.

Comment: @OpenStack the number of keys and order by default (json.net) make no difference to deserialization.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: When I talked about `no.of keys and order of keys`, I had C# Substring function in my mind. I initially though about using JSON.NET to desterilize the object but then I thought if the structure does not match, I may not get the desired result. Your answer now makes much more sense. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  only `userId` attribute is planned to use, you can simply declare an object with `userId` member and deserialize json. any other attributes will be omitted during deserialization.

```
class UserIDObj
{
   public string UserId { get; set; }
}

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserIDObj>("{\"name\":\"XX\", \"userId\":\"YYY\",\"age\":\"10\"}");
string usrID = obj.UserId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by @Wiktor Stribiżew also works like a charm. I am pasting his solution.

`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(myString, "\"userId\":\"([^\"]+)").Groups[1].Value`

Answer (score -2):

You could do this:

```
var needle = "\"userId\":"; // also you forgot to escape the quote here
var index = myString.IndexOf(needle); 
if(index != -1){
  var afterTheUserId = myString.Substring(index + needle.Length);
  var quoteIndex = afterTheUserId.IndexOf('"');
  // do what you want with quoteIndex
}
```

But as Eric Philips and PhonicUK said, you should use a proper JSON parser instead of writing your own string functions.

Comment: I cannot use `myString.Substring(index + needle.Length);`. As I said, I am not sure about the JSON input. The order of keys and names of keys are not fixed.

Comment: Why can't you use `myString.Substring(index + needle.Length);` ?

Comment: @OpenStack: JSON doesn't require key/value pairs to be in any particular order. From e.g. Wikipedia: ["an unordered collection of name/value pairs where the names (also called keys) are strings"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example).

Comment: I don't understand why my answer is downvoted, I mean I agree that it's clearly not a good way to parse OP's JSON code, but I'm answering the question.